# Can GCC be instructed not to eliminate dead code?

Tags: c, gcc

Suppose that I'm using a modern version of `GCC` to compile a C program. Furthermore, consider that my program contain stale branches, but that I'd very much like the dead code in those stale branches to be compiled and present in the final program. Consider the following program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = 0;
    goto skip;
        a = -1;
    skip: ;
    return a;
}
```

Clearly, if I use `GCC` with default optimization settings, the second assignment will never make it to the final program,  as the compiler can easily tell that it'll never be executed. Suppose that I don't want this to happen.

In `GCC`, there are a number of flags that dabble with dead code (most notably `-fdce`), and I can chose to explicitly deactivate these when invoking GCC accordingly:

```
-fno-dce
-fno-dse
-fno-tree-dce
-fno-tree-dse
```

As far as I can tell, this should instruct `GCC` not to mess with the second assignment. Yet, the concerned code never seems to make it into my program.

Why does `GCC` insist on removing the dead code, and is there a way of instructing GCC *not* to get rid of the second assignment?

Comment: Which gcc version are you using?

Comment: I'm aware of `volatile`, but I'm curious as to whether or not this is possible to do with GCC. As for GCC I'm using version 4.8.3, but I'd be interested in knowing if there's a solution any given version!

Comment: Disregard my comment. Volatile doesn't prevent GCC from skipping the assignment.

Comment: You could include a volatile variable in a conditional statement, e.g. `volatile int a = 0; if (!a) goto skip; ...`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That doesn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: @remyabel You sure? I get this output: http://hastebin.com/wuhibunowa.xml

Comment: it should be `-fno-dce`, etc. (note one less `-`).

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond, I was on the tube back home from work and had to spend some time digging up a PC with a somewhat new GCC. Thanks for the correction @SanderDeDycker, I was being very hopeful that this was the issue, but I'm afraid it doesn't help on my setup (now running 4.6.x). I'll be sure to correct it in the question body though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-fno-*` options don't work for me either with gcc-4.9.2.
That said, I think the following should be portable for all gcc (4.5+) targets:

```
__asm__ goto (""::::no_skip);
goto skip;

no_skip:
    a = -1;

skip:;
```

From the manual: "an asm goto statement is always implicitly considered volatile."

Furthermore, with gcc-4.8 and above, you might consider adding an attribute to let the compiler know that this is an 'unlikely' path. This helps prevent branching penalties, etc., that might otherwise occur when taking the 'expected' path:

```
no_skip: __attribute__ ((cold));
```

It stands to reason that you could also use:

```
skip: __attribute__ ((hot));
```

Comment: Thank you. This begs the question of why my example is not considered dead code by GCC, or at least why the given flags do not encompass the second assignment (perhaps the stale branch is so obviously not reachable that it is eliminated at an earlier stage not affected by the options).

Comment: @Caterpillar - I suspect you're right, that the unreachable code is eliminated at an earlier point. Another possibility is that the documentation doesn't precisely track development. The [internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Edges.html#Edges) document seems to have some interesting details.